# Align My Html Content through CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a slight problem in my css, i am trying to create 2 column layout and i see a random gaps in between contents. i am not able to explain it properly, please check the sample which i have created in jsfiddle. you will be able to understand. right side i am trying to create 2 column.

here is the jsfiddle link
    http://jsfiddle.net/QZJJL/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainsection">
   <div class="visitMainSection">
      <div class="VISIT headingsection">Open Site Visits</div>
      <div class="scrolldiv visit_repeatSection1" style="">
         <div class="header sectionheader TODAY">TODAY</div>
         <div class="content TODAY_1">
            <div class="leftColumn">
               <div class="ellipsis">
                  <h3 class="label1"><span class="facid">4002</span><span class="facName"> ABC Comapny Ltd.(Ark Bal Cave)</span></h3>
               </div>
               <p class="facLocalName" style="display: none;"></p>
               <p class="facAddress">Building 5, 6th floor Darjaling Road, Shan District CAV</p>
               <p class="label4"><span class="city">Shenzhen</span><span class="state"> Gurgao</span><span class="country"> India</span></p>
               <p class="label5"><span class="longitude" style="display: none;"></span><span class="latitude" style="display: none;"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rightColumn">
               <div class="rightGroup">
                  <div class="groupproto">
                     <h3><span class="protocolname show"> Test Protocol 10</span>                      <span class="date_class show"> NOV 18 - NOV 30, 2013</span></h3>
                  </div>
                  <p class="onsiteLead bold" style="display:none;">ONSITE LEAD: <span></span></p>
                  <div class="multirow">
                     <div>
                        <h5 class="audit_com" style="display:none;">Golder</h5>
                        <h5 class="auditor">J1</h5>
                        <p      class="assignments">Antidsdsdsdsd<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">Y1 (Lead)</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">dsdsdsdsdsdsdsd</p>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <h5 class="audit_com" style="display:none;">Verite</h5>
                        <h5 class="auditor">S1</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">Wages &amp; Benefits<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">C1 (Lead)</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">antidiscrimas<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">D1</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">antidiscrimas<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights<br>Wages &amp; Benefits</p>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <h5 class="audit_com" style="display:none;">PWC</h5>
                        <h5 class="auditor">L1 (Lead)</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">antidiscrimas<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">M1</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">Labor &amp; Human Rights<br>Wages &amp; Benefits</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">M2</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">Antidiscrimination<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights<br>Wages &amp; Benefits</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">V1</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">Antidiscrimination<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights<br>Wages &amp; Benefits</p>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <h5 class="audit_com" style="display:none;">Supplier Responsibility</h5>
                        <h5 class="auditor">G1 (Lead)</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">antidiscrimas<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights<br>Wages &amp; Benefits</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">R1</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">antidiscrimas<br>Labor &amp; Human Rights</p>
                        <h5 class="auditor">R2</h5>
                        <p class="assignments">Labor &amp; Human Rights<br>Wages &amp; Benefits</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footer">
                     <input type="button" class="setupButton" value="Visit Setup" style="display:none;">                      
                     <p class="downloadBriefcase"> </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="linkButton">                     <input type="button" class="lplinkbutton" value="&gt;" onclick="top.openPageURL('Pushinfolet?id=101652&amp;proc=146194&amp;flag=1&amp;emd=2&amp;accessflag=2&amp;edit_flag=D&amp;wrapper=no')" style="height: 558px;">                  </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
  min-height: 100%;
}
.headingsection {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 5;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
.mycustcls{
  background-color:  white;
  padding-left:  5;
}
.sectionheader{
  background-color:  #C2C2C2;
  color:  white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight:  500;
  font-size:  16px;
 }
.sectionspacer{
  height:20px;
}
.sectionrows{
  background-color:  rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93);
  padding:  10;
  padding-right: 0;
  overflow:  hidden;
}
.colsheader{
  height:  auto; 
  color:  white;
  font-weight:  500;
  font-size:  14px;
  float:  left;
  }
.sectioncols{
  width:  300px; 
  height:  auto; 
  float:  left;
  color:  black;
  font-weight:  normal;
  font-size:  13px;
  }
  .mainsection{
  padding:10px;
  }
.anotherspacer{
  background-color:  rgba(231, 231, 231, 0.72);
}
.rowseparator{
  border: 2px solid #CFCFCF;
}
  .content { clear: both; font-size: 13px;}
  .Separator {border-top: 2px solid #858585;}
  .date_class { float:right; font-weight: normal; }
  .rightGroup { float: left; width:80%;}
  .anchor{cursor:pointer;font-weight:500;}
  .linkbutton {}

.lplinkbutton{
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(173, 172, 172, 0.12); }


.scrolldiv{
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #858585;
    width: 1237px;
}
 .colfacility_id,.colfacility_name{
  font-weight:600;
  text-decoration:underline;
 }
 .colfacility_id,.colfacility_local_name,.colfacility_address,.colcity,.collongitude{width:500px;padding-top:2px;}
 .colprotocol_name{
    font-weight:500;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:500px;
  }
  .hidden{display:none;}
  .colname{font-weight:600;}
  .colfacility_address.colfacility_local_name,.colname{padding-top:5px; width: 235px;}
  .offlineclass{width:170px;color:black;font-size:  13px;} 
  .downloadasmnt{
    width: 73px;
    height: 29;
    border: 1px solid rgb(49, 120, 153);
    border-radius: 6;
    background-color: rgba(173, 172, 172, 0.94);
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .datefloat{
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .datefloat,.offlineclass{
    font-weight:normal;
    float:right;
  }
  /*div.tt_upcoming.sectionheader{
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93);
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}*/
.sectionheader u.anchor{
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 17;
  margin-left: 6;
}
.protocoldate{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.tt_upcoming.sectionheader{
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93) !important;
  color: black !important;
}
.capMainSection .sectionheader{ display:none;}
.leftColumn { float: left; width: 45%; padding: 15px 0 10px 20px;}
.rightColumn {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; /* add this to make linkbutton position relative to parent*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
.rightColumn .rightGroup { padding-top: 10px; }

.rightGroup .multirow div { float: left; width: 245px; }


.content p { margin: 5px 0;}

.groupproto { padding-top: 4px;}
.groupproto .protocolname{ 
  float: left;
  width: 313px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block; }

.leftColumn .ellipsis { }

.leftColumn h3.label1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin-bottom: 7px;}

.show{ display: block;}

.groupproto { margin-bottom:5px; }
.lasActivity ul { padding-left: 18px !important;}



h3 { font-weight: 500; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; height: 16px; margin:5px 0 10px 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 1.1em;}
h3.label1 { text-decoration: underline; border: 0;}
h5 { margin: 5px 0; font-weight: 600; font-size: 13px;}
.content { overflow: hidden;}
.downloadBriefcase { float: right;}
h3.normalCase { text-transform: none; border: 0;}
p.bold { font-weight: 600; font-size: 13px;}
.setupButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #727272;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 3px 0;}

.onsiteLead span { font-weight: normal; }

.UPCOMING { 
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #858585;}
.UPCOMINGContent .leftColumn { padding-top: 30px;}
.UPCOMINGContent .rightGroup { padding-top: 27px; }
```

Comment: can u give some color difference btwn the colums where the problem came

Comment: @Reshma : can you see gap between Yasmin SGM (Lead) and Leo GSM (Lead) ?

Comment: try using more organised styling in CSS....HTML5 has lots of predefined divs to cater to your needs....!! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5SWJy/ try this

Answer (score 0):

You should use tables instead of div for your data layout, because it's tabular data (this doesn't apply to general page layout). The problem is not that your two column layout doesn't work, it's that your layout is a multi line with two column in each. You may reorganize your layout in a two column layout.
Some suggestions of layout:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>A title in the first column</h3>
            <p>some text</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>A title in the 2nd column</h3>
            <p>some text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <!-- put the other lines here -->
</table>
```

With this layout, the rows will be aligned. It's the correct one for tabular data.

```
<div><!-- the container -->
    <ul style="float:left;"><!-- the left column container, using a class for csss is better -->
        <li>
            <h3>A title in the first column</h3>
            <p>some text</p>
        </li>
        <!-- put the other lines for left column here -->
    </ul>
    <ul><!-- the right column container -->
        <!-- same as for the left column -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this layout, rows will not be alligned. It's the correct one if you consider your data is an unordered list.

Comment: You definitely don't need to use tables or lists for this.

Comment: You don't, but it's far better for readablity and semantics. You can do everything with div, especially an unreadable code.

Comment: Debatable, how is a table or a list better for semantics when the data included isn't fit for a list or a table? You shouldn't be using a table to control the presentation of the page. Is the content _really_ a list?

Comment: You're right, a table is not intended for page layout, it's intended for tabular data, and it's the case here. You can say it's unordered list aswell. Anyway, what is his data is SJ-B business, that's why I let him choice between table or list.

Comment: I will agree that the question is clearly asking about tabular data, but my point was your answer isn't clear on this. It's making it out as if tables should be used for general layout usage. I still disagree with it being an unordered list though.

Comment: That's ok, you can have a different opinion, it doesn't hurt me. For the point you think my question isn't clear enough on table intended for general layout/tabular data layout, it's debatable too, because I was talking about the current specific example of course, not generally. But I'll edit my question, like you suggested, to be sure to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put content in col1, then next in col2, then next in col1 etc. etc.

If the content heights don't match, which in the fiddle they don't, you're going to get 'random' spaces where two blocks of content don't match.

The best way around this is to populate column 1 first, then populate column 2. In this way, the content heights won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

```
.leftColumn { float: left; width: 45%; padding: 15px 0 10px 20px;}
```

`width : 45%` is taking the unseen space, assign a lesser %age to it.

**Solution**

```
.leftColumn { float: left;  padding: 15px 0 10px 20px;border:1px solid #000}
```